# Mysql query function "select"

Tags: php, mysql

The query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...` scrolls through the list and returns the corresponding elements? or use other ways?
If I have a table of 10000 lines what makes the query?
Here is an example used for a login:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$ username' AND password = '$ password'", $con);

$row = mysql_fetch_array ($ result);
```

My question is, if I have a table with many rows does not become heavy?

Comment: It is a good practice to get only needed data from database. You may use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database with 100000 rows are not "huge". Its not a problem at all.

But for greater performances you can use the `LIMIT` function.

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $username ."' AND password = '". $password ."' LIMIT 1", $con);
```

Now MySQL will stop parsing after it finds one result.

Answer (score 0):

if "username" is unique and indexed (it should  be indexed for better performance) in mysql table then query can be used without "limit"